# What is the difference between jQuery serialize() method vs JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Maybe I'm getting this all mixed up, but reading about jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/) method has gotten be confused. I normally use `JSON.stringify()` when I need to serialize an object for an AJAX request. Are these two methods similar in any way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` produces `application/json` data from a JavaScript object or array.

`jQuery.serialize` produces `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (the standard encoding for HTML form submissions) from a jQuery object containing an HTML Form Element or a set of form controls.

Comment: Alright and would they be used for different scenarios or can I use them interchangeably? For example, is `JSON.stringify` just for objects/arrays and `jQuery.serialize` just for submitting forms?

Comment: They take different input and give different output, so you can't use the interchangeably.